# Can't change variable from within firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider) function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I have defined a variable called ***testVariable*** and set it to *initial* inside of the ***$scope.signIn()*** function. Then inside the ***firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then()*** function I changed it to *changed*. When I ***console.log()*** outside the ***firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then()*** function it returns *initial*. I want it to return *changed*, what is wrong with the code below? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", function ($scope){
    $scope.googleSignInStyle = {};
    $scope.googleSignInText = "";
    $scope.signIn = function (){
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        var testVariable = "initial";

        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            var user = result.user;
            var providerData = user.providerData[0];

            firebase.database().ref('users/' + providerData.displayName).set({Email: providerData.email, PhotoURL: providerData.photoURL, uid: providerData.uid});

            testVariable = "changed";

        }).catch(function(error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            var email = error.email;
            var credential = error.credential;
            console.log ("Error! Error code: " + errorCode + ", Email: " + email + ", Credential: " + credential + ". That's all we know.");
        });

        console.log (testVariable);
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your call to .then() runs asynchronously. That means that it will run some time later when  `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)` is returned.

So you are effectively changing the value of testVariable but after you printed it out. In other words, what happens inside .then() happens after you call console.log(testVariable)

If you are not familiar with the concept of promises [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Is it possible to delay the rest of the code until the .then() function is complete. What I am trying to do is once the user signs in, I want to change the sign in with google button to say their name. To do this all I have to do is change the variable `$scope.googleSignInText` to the username. The problem is that I can't change variables from within the .then() function for some reason.

Comment: The behaviour of a promise is to run asynchronously and execute the then part after the promise is completed. So the rest of the code can not wait on the then to be done

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to log it outside of the `signInWithPopup` callback. Your `testVariable` wont have any value since the `signInWithPopup` is assynchronous and it will not have finishied proccessing by the time you call `console.log`.

```
$scope.signIn = function (){
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    var testVariable = "initial";

    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        var user = result.user;
        var providerData = user.providerData[0];

        firebase.database().ref('users/' + providerData.displayName).set({Email: providerData.email, PhotoURL: providerData.photoURL, uid: providerData.uid});

        testVariable = "changed";
        console.log (testVariable);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        var email = error.email;
        var credential = error.credential;
        console.log ("Error! Error code: " + errorCode + ", Email: " + email + ", Credential: " + credential + ". That's all we know.");
        console.log (testVariable);
    });
}
```

Solving it will depend on what behavior you are trying to achieve. The code above is one possible solution, note that I have just insert the `console.log` call inside the callbacks.